# Include ImageMagick in MonoTouch

Tags: objective-c, mono, xamarin.ios, imagemagick

What's the best way to use ImageMagick in MonoTouch?

Adding the ImageMagickNET lib seems to produce errors during runtime, such as:

> Method
>   'Module:CrtImplementationDetails.DoDllLanguageSupportValidation
>   ()' in assembly
>   '/ImageMagickNET/bin/ReleaseQ8/ImageMagickNET.dll'
>   contains native code that cannot be
>   executed by Mono on this platform. The
>   assembly was probably created using
>   C++/CLI.

There are iPhone-specific binaries available, I suppose I have to link the whole library as described here:

http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Binding_New_Objective-C_Types

?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that error answers your question for you :

> in assembly '/ImageMagickNET/bin/ReleaseQ8/ImageMagickNET.dll' contains native code that 
>   cannot be executed by Mono on this
>   platform.

A quick google tells me on [the imagemagick codeplex page](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/)
that you're probably using what is called a 'wrapper'.

this means that the imagemagick code itself is still non-.NET imagemagick, which will never run on your iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

First, why this does not work.

Second, what you can do about it.

Why it does not work: The library that you are using is compiled with C++/CLI compiler against the Microsoft libraries.

All managed code that you use in MonoTouch must be compiled using MonoTouch's assemblies and tools, so the above wont work for two reasons: (a) Mono lacks a C++/CLI compiler and (b) even if that existed, you would have to reference the Mono asseblies

What can you do about it: You can build ImageMagic with Apple's C compiler, and then link the resulting code into your application:

http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Linking_Native_Libraries

Then for each ImageMagick method that you want to access, you need to wrap it using P/Invoke, a guide is available here:

http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries